# Virtual machine- setup centos as router

Tags: linux, centos, vmware, vmware-workstation

Here is my situation,

i need to configure linux system as router and client are also in virtual machine..

### System A

#### eth0: takes ip from isp(Configured as Bidge in VM ware)

#### eth1:

```
DEVICE=eth1
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=00:0c:29:0a:eb:ec
IPADDR=192.168.100.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPV6INIT=no
TYPE=Ethernet
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=192.168.100.1
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
```

#### Controls IP packet forwarding

net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

> route add -net 192.168.100.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.100.1 dev eth1

This is so far what i have done in system A....
and in System B
I have configured static IP address

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=00:0c:29:0a:eb:ec
IPADDR=192.168.100.2
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.100.1
```

Both System A and System B are Virtual OS. SystemA is considered as router and System B is considered as client...

AM i missing something...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Adding the route is wrong. That route will be added automatically as it's an interface connected route.

What you probably did wrong is not configuring a DNS server.

If you provide more details we can give a better answer.